# Redirect alias to different servers based on port

Tags: oracle, apache, virtualhost, cname, oracle-http-server

I have an Oracle HTTP Server (which is based on Apache) with two applications on it:

- `http://example.net/` -> opens the **Life**-Application (default port 80)
- `http://example.net:7777/` -> opens the **Test**-Application

Now we want to simplify the URL, actually it should be like this:

- `http://application` -> opens the Life-Application `http://example.net/`
- `http://application-t` -> opens the Test-Application `http://example.net:7777/`

We added DNS records for `application -> example.net` and `application-t -> example.net`, however it cannot point to certain ports. (i.e. `application-t` -> `example.net:7777` is not possible)

I tried to configure [VirtualHost](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/) but I failed. Both, `http://application` and `http://application-t` are always open the Life-Application, no matter what I tried.

How to setup the VirtualHost directive? Or do I have to make it differently?

Answer (score 0):

The "ProxyPass" and "ProxyPassReverse" parameters are used to tell Apache how to proxy requests. They require the "mod_proxy.so" and "mod_proxy_http.so" Apache modules, which are loaded by default in RHEL5 and RHEL6, but check the following lines are uncommented in the "/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf" file to make sure.
>

> LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
>
> LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so

Try Below VirtualHost Configurations

http://application -> opens the Life-Application http://example.net/

> <VirtualHost *:80>
>
> ```
> ServerName application
> ServerAlias application
> #DocumentRoot /var/www/html/application
> ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/application-error_log
> TransferLog /var/log/httpd/applicatin-access_log
> ProxyPass / http://example.net/        
> ProxyPassReverse / http:://example.net/
> ```
>
> </VirtualHost>

http://application-t -> opens the Test-Application http://example.net:7777/

> <VirtualHost *:80>
>
> ```
> ServerName application-t
> ServerAlias application-t
> #DocumentRoot /var/www/html/application-t
> ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/application-t-error_log
> TransferLog /var/log/httpd/application-t-access_log
> ProxyPass / http://example.net:7777/         
> ProxyPassReverse / http:://example.net:7777/
> ```
>
> </VirtualHost>

I hope it works

Comment: I cannot have two `<VirtualHost *:80>` in one config file. It opens always "http://example.net/". Two apache processes cannot listen to the same port 80. I will ask out IT to change the DNS record from *Alias* to sole entry. I assume then I can use `ServerName` value because now it is always the same.

Comment: u can add two &lt;VirtualHost *:80&gt; in one config file with different ServerName in one Apache.
I can share my youtube video link if you need

Comment: Yes, please. For me it did not work. But I will try again. Perhaps I have to remove `DocumentRoot` and `ServerName` value from root level of config file.